# Bootstrap 3 + simple_forms checkboxes

Tags: simple-form, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to integrate bootstrap 3 with simple_forms (from master).

Right now, I have the following:

**config/initializers/simple_form.rb:**

```
SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  config.wrappers :default, class: :input,
    hint_class: :field_with_hint, error_class: :field_with_errors do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.optional :maxlength
    b.optional :pattern
    b.optional :min_max
    b.optional :readonly
    b.use :label_input
    b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :hint }
    b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :error }
  end

  config.default_wrapper = :default
  config.boolean_style = :nested
  config.button_class = 'btn'
end
```

**config/initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb:**

```
SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  config.input_class = 'form-control'

  config.wrappers :bootstrap, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.use :label
    b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'controls' do |ba|
      ba.use :input
      ba.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-inline' }
      ba.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
    end
  end

  config.wrappers :prepend, tag: 'div', class: "form-group", error_class: 'error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.use :label
    b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'controls' do |input|
      input.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'input-prepend' do |prepend|
        prepend.use :input
      end
      input.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
      input.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-inline' }
    end
  end

  config.wrappers :append, tag: 'div', class: "form-group", error_class: 'error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.use :label
    b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'controls' do |input|
      input.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'input-append' do |append|
        append.use :input
      end
      input.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
      input.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-inline' }
    end
  end

  config.default_wrapper = :bootstrap
end
```

**app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.haml**

```
%div.panel.panel-auth
  %div.panel-heading
    %h3.panel-title Sign in
  %div.panel-body
    = simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f|
      .form-inputs
        = f.input :email, :required => false, :autofocus => true
        = f.input :password, :required => false
        = f.input :remember_me, :as => :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable?
      .form-actions
        = f.button :submit, "Sign in"
      %hr
    = render "devise/shared/links"
```

But the generated HTML is wrong. Well, it's right according to BS2, but wrong to BS3. Here it is:

```
<div class="form-group boolean optional user_remember_me">
  <label class="boolean optional control-label" for="user_remember_me">
    Remember me
  </label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input name="user[remember_me]" type="hidden" value="0">
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input class="boolean optional form-control" id="user_remember_me" name="user[remember_me]" type="checkbox" value="1">
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

But it actually should be something like:

```
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
    </label>
  </div>
```

It's probably possible to fix this hacking around wrappers, but I can't get it working.
Can someone give me some advice about that?

Cheers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like you said, you can get it working with a custom wrapper:

```
 config.wrappers :checkbox, tag: :div, class: "checkbox", error_class: "has-error" do |b|

    # Form extensions
    b.use :html5

    # Form components
    b.wrapper tag: :label do |ba|
      ba.use :input
      ba.use :label_text
    end

    b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: :p, class: "help-block" }
    b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: "help-block text-danger" }
  end
```

Which you then reference in your input:

```
 = f.input :remember_me, :as => :boolean, :wrapper => :checkbox if devise_mapping.rememberable?
```

Note however this won't work for collection_check_boxes:

```
= f.input :roles, as: :check_boxes, wrapper: :checkbox, collection: @employee_roles, label: false
```

You could try hacking together a custom input for the latter case, but it's a bit messy. Maybe somebody else knows a better way... and perhaps simple_form will catch up with bootstrap 3 soon enough.

Comment: didn't work. It still adding the 'form-control' class, which mess everything up. :/

Comment: It's adding a "form-control" class? I don't see that in your initializer... unless you meant "form-group"? If not, something else might be going on (perhaps a custom input?). Make sure you restart your server after changing the simple_form_bootstrap.rb initializer though or the change won't take effect. Just tested again on my end and it's working fine with "wrapper: :checkbox" in the input line.

Comment: Mind you I'm also using the master branch of simple_form (version 3.0.0)... it's quite possible there was a change from the version being referenced by rubygems (2.1.0). Try changing your gemfile reference to: "gem 'simple_form', github: 'plataformatec/simple_form'" and running gem update

Comment: This worked for me with a small amount of tweaking. Be sure to add the option `:wrapper => :checkbox` on your form input.

Comment: This worked for me to, thx! You  don't have to specify :wrapper => :checkbox for each input field just add this in top of your simple_form initialiser:   config.wrapper_mappings = { :boolean => :checkbox }

Comment: This doesn't work for me with the release version of Bootstrap 3 and Simple Form 3.0.0, however the answer below by @taras-taday does.

Answer (score 2):

Next configuration works perfectly for me with bootstrap 3:

```
SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  ...
  config.boolean_style = :inline
  ...
end
```

Simple custom wrapper

```
config.wrappers :inline_checkbox, :tag => 'div', :class => 'checkbox', :error_class => 'has-error' do |b|
  b.use :html5
  b.use :placeholder
  b.use :label_input
end
```

Usage:

```
= f.input :remember_me, :label => t('user.remember_me'), :as => :boolean, :wrapper => :inline_checkbox
```

Comment: Using the release version of Bootstrap 3 and Simple Form 3.0.0 this works perfectly, where as the accepted answer by @mwalsher does now.

Comment: Do you put this in simple_form.rb or simple_form_bootstrap.rb?

Answer (score 1):

I found a really simple solution for Bootstrap 3 checkboxes.  Assuming you already have the bootstrap 3 wrapper configured, all I had to do is add a custom input in `app/inputs` as `checkbox_input.rb`:

```
class CheckboxInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::BooleanInput
  # this exists to make the default 'boolean' css class in the form-group to be 'checkbox' instead
end
```

and use it via:
`= f.input :remember_me, :as => :checkbox if devise_mapping.rememberable?`

This will change the css `boolean` on the `form-group` to be `checkbox` instead, which will get the proper styling.

Similarly, here is a version for `radio-inline`

```
class RadioInlineInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::CollectionRadioButtonsInput

  # by default, this omits labels.  You should use f.label before this to stick a label where you would like.
  def initialize(builder, attribute_name, column, input_type, options = {})
    super(builder, attribute_name, column, :radio_buttons, {label: false}.merge(options))
  end

  def item_wrapper_class
    'radio-inline'
  end
end
```

Used as:

```
= f.label :frequency
= f.input :frequency, collection: @membership_plan.interval_frequencies, as: :radio_inline
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick way to fix the checkbox issue whilst we wait for Rafael to implement Bootstrap3: https://github.com/wtfiwtz/simple_form_bootstrap3/commits/master

Make sure you add "config.bootstrap3 = true" to your initializer...

Answer (score 0):

I have next requirements for my checkbox:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="hidden" value="0" name="...">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="..."> Label text
    </label>
</div>
```

Hidden input was extracted from label since it does not check checkbox on label click. I do not know why but I was not able to generate such html just using config so here is config + custom input class

```
# Config
config.wrappers :checkbox, tag: :div, class: "checkbox", error_class: "has-error" do |b|
  # Form extensions
  b.use :html5
  b.use :placeholder

  b.use :input

  b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: :p, class: "help-block" }
  b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: "help-block text-danger" }
end

# Input goes to app/inputs/inline_checkbox_input.rb
class InlineCheckboxInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base
  def input
    out = ''
    out << @builder.hidden_field(attribute_name, value: 0).html_safe
    out << "<label>"
    out << @builder.check_box(attribute_name, {}, 1, nil)
    out << "#{options[:label]}</label>"
    out
  end
end

# Usage
= f.input :name, :label => 'Label text', :wrapper => :checkbox, :as => :inline_checkbox
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this:

```
<%= f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean, :label => false, :inline_label => "Remember me" if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
```

Comment: Everyone keeps recommending this solution, but it doesn't work for me.